Captures keep giving me the same value when enabling both channels of TIM4 in Input Capture Mode
Hardware:

Test bench that generates two PWM signals ( A and B )
Cable that connect the test bench to the other board
Other board that retrieves the PWM signals (Port D pin 12 and 13 ) and has to calculate Duty Cycle and Frequency.

Library: Standard Peripheral Library ( I have to use this one )
What I did:

Enabled Input Capture Mode on CH1 on Rising Edge ( Note that BothEdge gave me some problems so I opted to not use it), SlaveMode_Reset, Enabled CC1 interrupt
Enabled Input Capture Mode on CH2 on Rising Edge ( Note that BothEdge gave me some problems so I opted to not use it), SlaveMode_Reset, Enabled CC2 interrupt
Inside the IRQ I clear the flag, read the captured value and switch capture mode to rising or falling , depending on the previous state.

Problem: When Enabling only CH1 the captured values are different and the calculated Duty Cycle is correct, but as soon as I enable the CH2 as well the CCR1 and CCR2 I get to read are the same for all captures ( I basically read only the rising edge)
Pin 12 Configuration Code:
void myPWM4_Config_1(tmyPWMInput *me)
{
    RCC_ClocksTypeDef __RCC_CLOCK;

    myPWMInputCtor(me);

    RCC_GetClocksFreq(&__RCC_CLOCK);
    me->clock = __RCC_CLOCK.PCLK1_Frequency * 2; //APB1

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &me->GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_TIM4);

    TIM4_IRQHandler_ptf = TIM4_IRQ_PWM;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM4_IRQn;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = 1;
    NVIC_Init(&me->NVIC_InitStructure);

    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 0xFFFF;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 840 - 1;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode=TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision= TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel         = TIM_Channel_1;
    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity      = TIM_ICPolarity_BothEdge;
    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection     = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler     = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
    me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter        = 0x0;

    TIM_ICInit(TIM4, &me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure);
    //TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM4, &me->TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure);
                                      // Select the TIM4Input Trigger: TI1FP1
    TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM4, TIM_TS_TI1FP1);
                                          // Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode
    TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);

    TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);
                           // Enables TIM4 peripheral Preload register on ARR.
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM4, ENABLE);
    // Configures the TIM8 Update Request Interrupt source (SETS the CR1->URS bit)
    //TIM_UpdateRequestConfig(TIM4, TIM_UpdateSource_Regular);

                            // Enable the CC1 and the update Interrupt Request
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC1, ENABLE);

    TIM_ClearFlag(TIM4, TIM_FLAG_Update);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
}


Pin 13 Configuration Code:
void myPWM4_Config_2(tmyPWMInput *me)
{
    RCC_ClocksTypeDef __RCC_CLOCK;

    myPWMInputCtor(me);

    RCC_GetClocksFreq(&__RCC_CLOCK);
    me->clock = __RCC_CLOCK.PCLK1_Frequency * 2; //APB1

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    me->GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &me->GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_TIM4);

    TIM4_IRQHandler_ptf = TIM4_IRQ_PWM;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM4_IRQn;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
    me->NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = 1;
    NVIC_Init(&me->NVIC_InitStructure);

    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 0xFFFF;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 840 - 1;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode=TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision= TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &me->TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel         = TIM_Channel_2;
    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity      = TIM_ICPolarity_BothEdge;
    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection     = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler     = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
    me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter        = 0x0;

    TIM_ICInit(TIM4, &me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure);
    //TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM4, &me->TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure);
                                      // Select the TIM4Input Trigger: TI2FP2
    TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM4, TIM_TS_TI2FP2);
                                          // Select the slave Mode: Reset Mode
    TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_SlaveMode_Reset);

    TIM_SelectMasterSlaveMode(TIM4, TIM_MasterSlaveMode_Enable);
                           // Enables TIM4peripheral Preload register on ARR.
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM4, ENABLE);
    // Configures the TIM8 Update Request Interrupt source (SETS the CR1->URS bit)
    TIM_UpdateRequestConfig(TIM4, TIM_UpdateSource_Regular);

                            // Enable the CC1 and the update Interrupt Request
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC2, ENABLE);

    TIM_ClearFlag(TIM4, TIM_FLAG_Update);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);
}


IRQ Code:
if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC1) != RESET) {
            tmyPWMInput *pPWM4_1 = &myCTRL.myHW.myPortDCfg.myPWM4_1; //PIN12
                              // Clear TIM8 Capture Compare1 interrupt pending bit
            TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC1);

            if ( is_rising_ch1 )
            {
                pPWM4_1->FullPeriod = TIM_GetCapture1(TIM4);

                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel         = TIM_Channel_1;
                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity      = TIM_ICPolarity_Falling;
                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection     = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler     = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter        = 0x0;
                TIM_ICInit(TIM4, &TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure);
                is_rising_ch1 = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                pPWM4_1->HighPeriod = TIM_GetCapture1(TIM4);

                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel         = TIM_Channel_1;
                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity      = TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection     = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler     = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
                TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter        = 0x0;
                TIM_ICInit(TIM4, &TIM_CH1_ICInitStructure);
                is_rising_ch1 = 1;
            }

            //To prevent division by 0 on duty cycle calculation
            if ( pPWM4_1->FullPeriod != 0 )
                myPWMCalc(pPWM4_1);


    }
    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC2) != RESET) {
            tmyPWMInput *pPWM4_2 = &myCTRL.myHW.myPortDCfg.myPWM4_2; //PIN13
                              // Clear TIM8 Capture Compare1 interrupt pending bit
            TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM4, TIM_IT_CC2);

            if ( is_rising_ch2 )
            {
                pPWM4_2->FullPeriod = TIM_GetCapture2(TIM4);

                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel         = TIM_Channel_2;
                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity      = TIM_ICPolarity_Falling;
                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection     = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler     = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter        = 0x0;
                TIM_ICInit(TIM4, &TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure);
                is_rising_ch2 = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                pPWM4_2->HighPeriod = TIM_GetCapture2(TIM4);

                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel         = TIM_Channel_2;
                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity      = TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection     = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler     = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
                TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter        = 0x0;
                TIM_ICInit(TIM4, &TIM_CH2_ICInitStructure);
                is_rising_ch2 = 1;
            }

            //To prevent division by 0 on duty cycle calculation
            if ( pPWM4_2->FullPeriod != 0 )
                    myPWMCalc(pPWM4_2);

    }



As I've told you already in the other thread, there is only one Slave-mode controller and by setting it in the second function you override the first one's setting. And I also already told you, that you should not reset the timer, but capture values from the free running timer and calculate the period by subtracting captured values for two consecutive edges of the same polarity (and then pulse length/duty by subtracting values captured for consecutive rising and falling edge).

@wek I've put BothEdge and get 3 captures, calculate the duty cycle and frequency. The only thing missing is this one: I calculate the period as 3rd capture minus the first one, high period as 2nd capture minus the first one. When calculating the duty I sometimes get the correct duty (for ex. 70%) and sometimes the duty cycle is ( 100% - effective duty cycle (70%) = 30) is there any way to workaround this? or what could possibly cause this?
